# React navigation doesn't refresh the page when parameter changed

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react navigation to navigate between pages.
I have 2 pages. Let's call them A and B. I have some cards on page A and has touchable opacities on cards to navigate to page B with a different id (using this id for getting data from the server).

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('pageB',{id:this.props.id})} >
   <Text>PageB</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

It works well on first navigate. But when I navigate back to page A (by using side menu) and select another navigation button to navigate page B (different parameter) it navigates me to the same page with first navigate.

I have tried to use navigation key like that but I guess I could do that;

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('pageB',{id:this.props.id}, this.props.id)}
```

Comment: can you please share how you get that value in page B from page A?

Comment: could you plz give us a little of your code. as Paras said you should get parameters like this : `this.props.navigation.getParam(paramName, defaultValue)`

Comment: `const { navigation } = this.props;
const firmId = navigation.getParam('id');`
I'm getting parameter on page B like that

Comment: try to use like this var param1 = navigation.getParam('param1', 'default_value');

Comment: i tried that too but doesnt make any difference

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the new Parameter like this:

```
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    let value = navigation.getParam("value");
    return {
        title: name,
        headerRight: () => (<Button title="Edit" onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Edit", { val: value})} />),
    };
```

And set somewhere always the new parameter like this:

```
let value = this.state.value;
this.props.navigation.setParams({value});
```